# Children of table-cell not taking up 100% height (only works in FF)

Tags: html, css

I wish to have equal height columns, so I have created a `display:table` container with `display:table-cell` children, both have `height:100%` set. The problem is, it works as I wished on Firefox only, but doesn't work on Chrome and IE11.

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/so4v6ms6/)

Below is the HTML code :

```
<div class="featured">
<div class="row">
    <div class="one-half">
        <div class="light-bg">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="one-quarter"><div class="icon icon-server icon-1"></div></div>
                <div class="three-quarter">
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the le text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the le
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="one-half">
        <div class="light-bg">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="one-quarter"><div class="icon icon-server icon-2"></div></div>
                <div class="three-quarter">
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the le
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS :

```
*,
*:before,
*:after { /* Inherit box-sizing to make it easier to change the property for components that leverage other behavior; see http://css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice/ */
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
.row{
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin-left:-10px;
    margin-right:-10px;
}
.row:before,
.row:after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.row:after{
    clear:both;
}

.one-half, .one-quarter, .three-quarter{
    float:left;
    padding:0 10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.one-half{
    width:50%;
}
.one-quarter{
    width:25%;
}
.three-quarter{
    width:75%;
}
.light-bg{
    background:#ddd;
}
.featured > .row{
    display:table;
    height:100%;
}
.featured > .row .one-half{
    display:table-cell;
    height:100%;
    float:none;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.featured > .row .light-bg{
    padding:20px;
    border-radius:4px;
    height:100%;
}
.featured > .row .light-bg .row{
    margin-bottom:0;
}

.featured > .row .light-bg h6{
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    color:#000;
}
.featured > .row .light-bg .icon{
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    height:96px;
    background:#fff;
}
```

Any ideas is greatly appreciated. I can't use flexbox because it's not supported in IE9.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since all browsers could detect the height of `.one-half` correctly (except Chrome), finally I used JavaScript to set its height explicitly to solve this problem for IE (and any other browsers) because the children elements use `height:100%`, and one of the children with this is the element with background colour.

As for Chrome, I had to apply `display:table;` to `.light-bg` to allow correct detection of height for `.one-half` parent.

Answer (score -1):

Make it flexible for any browsers

visit this learning site

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp

Comment: All the properties used are cross-browser compatible. That's why I'm not using flexbox.